# How to define order of differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know how to check order of differential equation but I need to know how to **define order of differential equation** in words. Please help me.

Comment: @celeriko, I understood it as asking how to *explain* what the order is.

Comment: @vonbrand I might have left it if it were not a cross post too http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500357/how-to-define-order-of-derivative (I voted to close the other as dupe).

Answer (score 3):

It is just the highest derivative that shows up. So $(y'')^2 + y' = 5$ is second order (but can be reduced to first order in $y'$). You might have to simplify first, e.g. $y'' = y'' + y' + 17 x$ is really $0 = y' + 17 x$, i.e., first order.

For a first view of the subject (like I understand you are presenting), don't get too nitpicky. Tying to go for maximal generality *will* just create endless confusion. When/if they have stumbled upon cases where nuances are important (yes, you can very well present those in class on purpose), you can explain what is going on and extend as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Order is the number of highest derivative present in the Differential Equation.